# Ruby CSV variables/arrays manipulation

Tags: ruby, csv

When executing the code below, both `first_name` and `last_name` variables/arrays give me the same output.

I assume it is intended and I'm just not understanding why, but how can I manipulate both variables without changing the other one?

```
require 'csv'
INPUTFILE1 = ARGV[0]

CSV.foreach(INPUTFILE1, headers:true) do |row|
first_name = row['username']
first_name.sub!(/^[^,]+,/, "")

puts first_name

last_name = row['username']
    last_name.sub!(something that has yet to be tested)

puts last_name
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that `first_name` is actually only a reference to an object in the map `row`. If you do not want to change the map itself, use `dup`:

```
first_name = row['username'].dup
first_name.sub!(/^[^,]+,/, "")
last_name = row['username'].dup
last_name.sub!(something that has yet to be tested)
```

`dup` is making a clone of the object you want to work on, meaning that it creates a new reference. Thus changing `first_name` will not affect the value in `row`. This is actually an implementation of the [Prototype design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern)

Alternatively in your case you can also do:

```
first_name = row['username']
first_name = first_name.sub(/^[^,]+,/, "")
```

Thus `sub` will create the new reference for you. You do not need to make changes in place.